How to code moving the .aar after building, in build.gradle.kts?
I'm writing an Android plugin for Unity in Android Studio (2023.1.1 patch 1), but to streamline my process, I would like the .aar to be built directly into a folder in my Unity project. To achieve this, I want to write a bit of code that moves the .aar from the original build folder to a different one after building completes.
The current project hierarchy in Android Studio is an AndroidProject, with a Module that is used to create the actual android plugin for use in Unity. The module has a build.gradle.kts.
Trying to search on how to do this has lead me to many different versions and iterations of gradle, kotlin, and other tools, with a lot of deprecated code or formatting that no longer works. I'm very new to android plugin development, and the lack of up to date tutorials makes the learning process extremely stunted (so far).
I've tried registering tasks with 'doLast', but nothing has worked so far.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? It sounds relatively simple but nothing I can find online has been relevant.

I found the solution through more searching and using AI tools to convert the found gradle code to kotlin. Adding this to your build.gradle.kts works to move it after build.
This code specifically moves the file to a Plugins folder that is in the same folder as the Android project folder, which is useful for Unity Packages.
tasks.register("copyAARDebug", Copy::class) {
    // build/outputs/aar
    from(file("${buildDir.absolutePath}${File.separator}outputs${File.separator}aar"))

    // mylibrary-debug.aar
    include("${project.name}-debug.aar")

    // <root_project_dir>/destination_dir/debug
    into(projectDir.parentFile.parentFile.resolve("Plugins"))

    // <root_project_dir>/destination_dir/debug/renamed.aar
    rename("${project.name}-debug.aar", "${project.name}.aar")
}

tasks.register("copyAARRelease", Copy::class) {
    // build/outputs/aar
    from(file("${buildDir.absolutePath}${File.separator}outputs${File.separator}aar"))

    // mylibrary-release.aar
    include("${project.name}-release.aar")

    // <root_project_dir>/destination_dir/release
    into(projectDir.parentFile.parentFile.resolve("Plugins"))

    // <root_project_dir>/destination_dir/release/renamed.aar
    rename("${project.name}-release.aar", "${project.name}.aar")
}

afterEvaluate {
    println("Executing afterEvaluateBlock")
    tasks.named("assembleDebug") {
        println("Configuring assembleDebug task")
        finalizedBy("copyAARDebug")
    }
    tasks.named("assembleRelease") {
        println("Configuring assembleRelease task")
        finalizedBy("copyAARRelease")
    }
}


Modified the above solution to work at least in a library build.gradle.kts file in my project.
I am sure this could be done better.
Instructions:
Inside your build.gradle.kts file paste the following code inside the android {} block
  tasks.register("copyAARFileRelease", Copy::class) {
        // gets the project directory
        val projectDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
        // relative to project directory, this was done inside a library gradle.build.tks! 
        val relativeAarSourcePath = "/AndroidUnitySerialDeviceConnector/build/outputs/aar"
        // again relative to the project directory
        val relativeArrDestinationPath = "../AdxControllerConnectorTE/Assets/Plugins/Android"

        val sourceDir = File(projectDir, relativeAarSourcePath)
        val destinationDir = File(projectDir, relativeArrDestinationPath)

        val aarFileName = "${project.name}-debug.aar"

        // Delete project files from destination directory
        delete(fileTree(destinationDir) {
            include("${project.name}*.aar")
            include("${project.name}*.meta")
        })

        // Copy .aar file to destination directory
        from(sourceDir)
        include(aarFileName)
        into(destinationDir)
    }

    tasks.register("copyAARFileDebug", Copy::class) {

        val projectDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
        val relativeAarSourcePath = "/AndroidUnitySerialDeviceConnector/build/outputs/aar"
        val relativeArrDestinationPath = "../AdxControllerConnectorTE/Assets/Plugins/Android"

        val sourceDir = File(projectDir, relativeAarSourcePath).absolutePath
        val destinationDir = File(projectDir, relativeArrDestinationPath)

        val aarFileName = "${project.name}-debug.aar"

        // Delete project files from destination directory
        delete(fileTree(destinationDir) {
            include("${project.name}*.aar")
            include("${project.name}*.meta")
        })

        // Copy .aar file to destination directory
        from(sourceDir)
        include(aarFileName)
        into(destinationDir)
    }
    // need to register the tasks
    afterEvaluate {
        println("Executing afterEvaluateBlock")
        tasks.named("assembleDebug") {
            println("Configuring assembleDebug task")
            finalizedBy("copyAARFileDebug")
        }
        tasks.named("assembleRelease") {
            println("Configuring assembleRelease task")
            finalizedBy("copyAARFileRelease")
        }
    }

Hope this is helpful.
